# Why is a gray scale image displayed green after adding salt and pepper noise and using median blur?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

Currently, I'm facing issues with an image where I put salt and pepper noise and after using the median blur the picture it's green even do the image in grayscale.

Original image:
[image]

Here's the code that I'm using. I convert the original picture into a grayscale one.

```
img1 = cv.imread('foto_1.jpeg',cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

[image]

Here I add the salt and pepper noise (I know it's not the best code, but I need to avoid using open cv since it's an instruction from my teacher).

```
ruido1 = np.zeros_like(img1)
cv.randu(ruido1, 0, 255)
x,y = img1.shape 
img_con_sp_1 = img1.copy()
prob = 0.00001
pixel
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        rdn = random.randint(205, 255)
        if ruido1[i][j] < int(255 - (rdn*(1-prob))):
            img_con_sp_1[i][j] = 0
        elif ruido1[i][j] > 255 - int(255 - (rdn*(1-prob))):
            img_con_sp_1[i][j] = 255
        else: 
            img_con_sp_1[i][j] = img1[i][j]
imshow("imagen con S&P 1",img_con_sp_1,size=12)
```

[image]

Here's the part where I'm using the median blur from open cv but the image it's getting green.

```
median_blur = cv.medianBlur(img1, 7)
plt.imshow(median_blur)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Can you please help me to know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You add the noise to a copy, but then you use the original for blur. I don't know if that is the problem, but it certainly doesn't seem right. I bet you could fix this by doing the blur before you even convert to grayscale. Then it simply wont matter if there is color after blur.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. If you are using Mathplotpy then it uses a color table to display images. The color is coming from the color table. Use a grayscale color table in place of the default one.

Comment: look at the `.dtype` and `.shape` of your arrays. matplotlib is sensitive to that. -- and no screenshots of code please. [mre] requires code as text. your post seems to be missing some crucial information.

Answer (score 2):

The image is not turned green, it's colorized according to Matplotlib's default colormap, `viridis`, i.e., blue for darker grays, green for intermediate values and yellow for light grays. I don't understand how can you claim that it's green. However...

From [`plt.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) documentation

> The input may either be actual RGB(A) data, or 2D scalar data, which will be rendered as a pseudocolor image. For displaying a grayscale image set up the colormapping using the parameters `cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255`.